# Group 200 samples into 10 groups so that you minimize the total of a measure

Tags: r

I have a network graph of 200 people with each node being a person, an edge being if they ever talked before, and edge weight being how much they communicate and I need to break them into 10 groups of 20 people so that we minimize the amount of communication between the groups. To clarify this, we want to create a networking meeting where each table is filled with people who haven't talked much in the past to increase collaboration.

**Bonus**

there will be 2 networking events during the same meeting and each person will be seated at 2 different tables so we need to do this twice will accounting for the fact that the first table will influence the second table decisions.

To do this, we calculated betweenness and got a value for all 200 people. My thought is if we can create groups that minimize the sum of the betweenness, we would in essence create groups that most likely would not have interacted before (or as much).

```
df = data.frame(id=1:200,measure=rnorm(200,mean=50,sd=10))
```

I'm a little stumped on how to get started here without going through a brute force method and first seeding each table with the top 20 people and then just going through one by one. Are there any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

We can order the df by the measure, then split it into equal groups such that the top 10 people are in different groups, the next 10 best are also in different groups, etc.

```
groups <- split( df[order(df$measure),], rep(1:10,20) )
```

If we sum the measures in each group we find that that are approximately all equal

```
 sapply(groups, function(x) sum(x$measure))

        1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9        10 
 990.9206  996.3302 1001.2337 1007.6482 1012.3790 1016.2626 1020.7649 1024.2977 1034.4867 1038.0016
```

---

Edit: We can make the groups even more even by reversing the grid order on the second half such that the best person is paired with the worst person

```
groups <- split( df[order(df$measure),], c(rep(1:10,10),rep(10:1,10)) )

sapply(groups, function(x) sum(x$measure))
       1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9       10 
990.1134 991.6504 994.7865 997.4595 996.7483 995.9476 995.3022 995.1354 995.2223 995.9747
```

Comment: Interesting approach! This could work. Any ideas on how to solve the "bonus" question. I would need to do that twice to create two separate sets. i.e first round of tables, than second round of tables.

Comment: You could make the groups half as big with `rep(1:20,10)` then just manually add pairs of groups together. You'll still get an equal balance of scores that way.

Comment: @TedMosby a non-manual way of achieving this would be `split(do.call(rbind,split(df[order(df$measure),], rep(1:20,10))), unlist(lapply(1:10, rep, 10)) )` its not clean but it does the trick.

Comment: @TedMosby, I've added an edit to further improve the grouping.